# Cambiar un ícono por otro al hacer click usando sólo CSS

Tags: bootstrap, reactjs, reactstrap, collapse

Tengo un `Sidebar` con componentes `UncontrolledCollapse` de la librería `reactstrap`. Estos componentes se despliegan al dar click en un link que tiene un `icon`de `font awesome`. (El ícono en cuestón es una flecha hacia la derecha)

Lo que yo quiero hacer es que, al hacer click y estar desplegado el componente, el icono cambie la flecha hacia la derecha por una flecha hacia abajo.

> PREGUNTA: Estoy trabajando en react y quiero hacerlo únicamente con CSS. Es posible hacerlo? (estoy usando sass)

La forma que se me ocurre es cambiando el UncontrolledCollapse por Collapse, para poder manejar el estado del componente, y tengo que crear un estado por cada componente Collapse.

Preferentemente quisiera buscar la forma de hacerlo unicamente con CSS. Alguien conoce alguna manera? Muchas gracias

```
      <li>
        <a color="primary" id="appointments">
          <i className='fas fa-calendar-alt icon-danger'></i>
        Turnos <i className='fas fa-angle-right icon-gray float-right pt-1'></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <UncontrolledCollapse toggler="#appointments">
        <li ><a href='/profile'><i className='fas fa-address-card icon-orange ml-4'> 
        </i>Crear Turno</a></li>
        <li><a href='/profile'><i className='fas fa-project-diagram icon-danger ml-4'> 
        </i>Bucar Turnos</a></li>
        <li><a href='/profile'><i className='fas fa-blog icon-info ml-4' ></i>Otro Menú</a> 
        </li>
      </UncontrolledCollapse>
```

> Actualmente se ve asi (el fragmento de codigo corresponde a `Usuarios`, el link `Turnos`es para que se vea uno cerrado y otro abierto):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No conozco mucho reactstrap, pero quizá puedas rotar la imagen después del clic con  `a::after { transform: rotate(90deg) }`

Comment: No, no me funcionó. Aunque si yo tiro el transform en el elemento a través del inspector del navegador funciona. Asi que debe haber algun problema con el selector. Gracias de todas maneras, voy a probar alternativas en torno a esto que me pasas.